# O meu delete está apagando os dados da tabela, mas não redirecionar para a página que eu quero

Tags: php, html, mysql

*NO CASO ELE EXIBE O "echo "erro ao apagar";" mesmo os dados terem sido apagado da tabela. Por favor me ajudem!

Página de funcoes:

```
 require 'conexao.php';

    function apagar($cod_pedido) {
        $link = conexao();
        $query = "delete from pedido_oracao where cod_pedido = '{$cod_pedido}'";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
      }
```

---

Página apagar pedidos.php:

```
<?php
require 'funcoes.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $cod_pedido = $_GET['cod_pedido'];

    if (apagar($cod_pedido)) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "erro ao apagar";
    }
}
```

Onde estou puxando no html:

```
<?php foreach ($dados as $lista) { ?>
....
....
....
....
<div class="cell cell2" data-title="Excluir">
                                <a class="excluir" href="apagarPedidos.php?cod_pedido=<?= $lista['cod_pedido'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                            </div>
    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

faltou retornar o status da mysqli_query...

```
function apagar($cod_pedido) {
    $link = conexao();
    $query = "delete from pedido_oracao where cod_pedido = '{$cod_pedido}'";
    return mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! MUITO OBRIGADO!

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso como alternativa.

```
function apagar($cod_pedido) {
    $link = conexao();
    $query = "delete from pedido_oracao where cod_pedido = '{$cod_pedido}'";
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("Erro");
}
```

Comment: Tinha esquicido do Return. Obg ai :)